# is it possible to execute trigger from php code

Tags: php, database

I taking url from user and getting text of that url using

```
$data=file_get_content($url)
```

I am extracting title, image url from this $data. And storing into table `urlrecord` and show it in div `D1` on front end.

after that I perform processing on `$data` which takes little time which gives me result `$x` and `$y`. (x and y i am not going to show in `D1`)

`x and y` also I have to store in `urlrecord` table.

If I perform processing on `$data` to get `x and y` before then showing url content in front end ie `D1` will be delayed.

So what I want is:

After storing URL content into table, I perform $data processing. And storing the $x and $y into same table.

bottomline is I dont want to reflect $data processing to get x,y to affect in show url content on front end.

Can some one think optimal scenario here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a cronjob to do the $data processing.

For example, there's a flag column in table urlrecord, default to 1, and the cronjob will scan the table every 5 mins, "select * from urlrecord where flag=1", calculate x and y, and update the flag to 2.